# Convert ase atoms to pymatgen structure

Tags: computational-chemistry, electron-correlation, pymatgen

I have `atom_row` from ase_db.
I have tried various methods but they all fail. Seems like I'm missing a lattice, but I don't know what that is and where I can get it for my structure.

Comment: Could you detail the various methods you tried and how they fail so that we don't ended up suggesting what you already tried?

Answer (score 7):

Try `AseAtomsAdaptor.get_structure` method from [pymatgen.io.ase](https://github.com/materialsproject/pymatgen/blob/master/pymatgen/io/ase.py), it actually serves exactly this purpose.

Comment: I tried this method but got an error, most likely because my atoms don't have bonds

Comment: @Dmitry Sokolov please, post your code and exact error stack trace here

Comment: code:  from pymatgen.io.ase import AseAtomsAdaptor
row = database.get(1)
AseAtomsAdaptor.get_structure(row.toatoms())

error: 
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     86 
     87 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 88     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     89 
     90 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix

I also have tried matador package, error was like no lattice or smth, I don't remember

Answer (score 1):

This is how I wound up getting things working.

I saved atom as xyz:

```
atoms = row.toatoms()
atoms.write(f"./{dir_}/{i}_{str(atoms.symbols)}.xyz")
```

Then, I opened the xyz in pymatgen:

```
from pymatgen.core import Molecule
structures = [Molecule.from_file(train_path 
               + '/' + file) for file in train_files]
```